# How to show the projections of 3D orbit on the three primary planes

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Perhaps this question has been asked before but even though I searched the site I did not find what I want.

The code is rather simple:

```
data = Import["orbit3d.out", "Table"];
d = Table[{data[[i, 2]], data[[i, 3]], data[[i, 4]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}];
l = Line[d];
S0 = Graphics3D[{Black, Thickness[0.002], l}];
P0 = Show[{S0}, Axes -> True, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed], PlotRange -> 5.5, ImageSize -> 550]
```

which produces the following plot

[image]

The complete data file can be obtained here: [data file](http://www.mediafire.com/download/t9iuvfeifttt4y4/orbit3d.out)

Now I want to produce the projections of the 3D orbit on the three priamry planes (x,y), (x,z) and (y,z) and plot them on the sides of the bounding box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: `P0/.{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ,z_?NumericQ}:>{x,y,0}` etc..BTW a self-contained example would be preferable - why should we need to download a file for this?

Comment: @YvesKlett I evaluated your command but it does not show anything. Can you give some more details?

Comment: @YvesKlett Now it's working but it does not produce what I want. I want the three projections of the 3D orbit to be shown as shadows on the sides of the bounding box.

Comment: @Vaggelis, it should be easy to change the `0` in Yves's snippet to something else. In any event, there was an old package function called `Shadow[]` you might want to search for…

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
data = Import["orbit3d.out", "Table"];

(* Your Table is not needed; you can use [[...]] instead *)
(*d=Table[{data[[i,2]],data[[i,3]],data[[i,4]]},{i,1,Length[data]}];*)
d = data[[All, 2 ;; 4]];

l = Line[d];

(* Projections on bounding box *)
lz = l /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, y, -5.5};
ly = l /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {x, 5.5, z};
lx = l /. {x_, y_, z_} -> {-5.5, y, z};

S0 = Graphics3D[{
        Black, Thickness[0.002], l,
        GrayLevel[0.7], lx, ly, lz
       },
       Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
       AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed],
       PlotRange -> 5.5, ImageSize -> 550
     ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many many thanks! This is exactly what I was wanted.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z No problem! Glad to help.