# 2D projection of a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, projection

how we can obtain a 2D projection of 3D plot. I would to have a plot like this :
[image]
PS: the plot is a publication paper.

Comment: possible duplicate: [How to project 3d image in the planes xy, xz, yz?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199612/125), See if [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199613/125) gives what you need.

Comment: What is the formula for the blue line?

Comment: @yarchik In LateX form: E(t)=\sin ^{2}(\pi t)\left[\sin (t) \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{x}}+\cos (t) \mathbf{e}_{\mathbf{y}}\right]

Comment: thank you so much 

Comment: It's hard to read Latex, please, add MA code to your post.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll[f, functions]
f[u_] := {u, (1 - u) Sin[10 u], (1 - u) Cos[10 u]/3};

plotrange = 4;
padding = .5;
```

Construct three additional functions replacing $i^{th}$ coordinate of `f[u]` with a constant corresponding to the plane of projection:

```
functions[u_] := Prepend[f[u]][
  MapThread[ReplacePart[f[u], # -> #2 (plotrange + padding)] &, 
    {{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 1, -1}}]]


ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@functions[u], {u, -Pi, Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> plotrange, 
 PlotRangePadding -> padding, 
 Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}]
```

[image]

**See also:**

1. [How to project 3d image in the planes xy, xz, yz?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199612/125)
2. [Ellipsoid and its projections](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173850/125)
3. [How to show the projections of 3D orbit on the three primary planes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92466/125)