# ParametricPlot3D Curve and ImplicitRegion: Projections and Intersections

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, numerical-value, boundary-conditions, projection

There is a parametric 3D-Curve:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[1 - 3 t], Sin[2 t - 1]}, {t, 0, 10}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

And Implicit Region:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[\[ScriptCapitalR], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotPoints -> 50, ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

How to project a 3D-curve is shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256965/2d-projection-of-a-3d-plot).

```
ClearAll[f, functions]
f[t_] := {Sin[t], Cos[1 - 3 t], Sin[2 t - 1]};
plotrange = 1;
padding = .1;

functions[t_] := 
 Prepend[f[t]][
  MapThread[
   ReplacePart[f[t], # -> #2 (plotrange + padding)] &, {{1, 2, 
     3}, {-1, 1, -1}}]]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@functions[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> padding, 
 Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

How to project `ImplicitRegion` is shown [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/formula-region-projections.html):

```
{RegionPlot[Resolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \(z\)]\({x, y, 
      z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]\)\), Reals], {x, -1, 
      1}, {y, -1, 1}], RegionPlot[Resolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \(y\)]\({x, y, 
      z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]\)\), Reals], {x, -1, 
      1}, {z, -1, 1}], RegionPlot[Resolve[\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \(x\)]\({x, y, 
      z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]\)\), Reals], {y, -1, 
      1}, {z, -1, 1}]}
```

[image]

Now, it is necessary to find the intersections of the projections of the three-dimensional curve with the projection of the implicit region onto the xy-yz-xz planes. How to do it in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y z + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 z + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 z + 
     y^6 + z^6 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[1 - 3 t], Sin[2 t - 1]}, {t, 0, 
    10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg]@{x, y, z}]];
regplot = 
  RegionPlot3D[reg, PlotPoints -> 50, Axes -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1], PlotRange -> All];
regxy = RegionPlot[
   Resolve[Exists[z, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]], {x, -1.5, 
    1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, BoundaryStyle -> Blue];
regyz = RegionPlot[
   Resolve[Exists[x, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]], {y, -1.5, 
    1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, BoundaryStyle -> Blue];
regxz = RegionPlot[
   Resolve[Exists[y, {x, y, z} ∈ reg]], {x, -1.5, 
    1.5}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, BoundaryStyle -> Blue];
plotxy = plot /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y}, 
    Graphics3D -> Graphics, RGBColor[a__] :> Cyan};
plotyz = plot /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {y, z}, 
    Graphics3D -> Graphics, RGBColor[a__] :> Green};
plotxz = plot /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, z}, 
    Graphics3D -> Graphics, RGBColor[a__] :> Purple};
GraphicsGrid[{{Show[regxy, plotxy], 
   Show[regyz, plotyz]}, {Show[regxz, plotxz], Show[plot, regplot]}}]
```

[image]

We use `RegionFunction` to restrict the parametric curve(we test another implicit region,not the disk)

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y z + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 z + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 z + 
     y^6 + z^6 <= 1, {x, y, z}];
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[t], Cos[1 - 3 t], Sin[2 t - 1]}, {t, 0, 
    10}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, RegionMember[reg]@{x, y, z}]];
plotxy = plot /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, y}, 
    Graphics3D -> Graphics, RGBColor[a__] :> Cyan};
plotyz = plot /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {y, z}, 
    Graphics3D -> Graphics, RGBColor[a__] :> Green};
plotxz = plot /. {{x_Real, y_Real, z_Real} :> {x, z}, 
    Graphics3D -> Graphics, RGBColor[a__] :> Purple};
GraphicsGrid[{{plotxy, plotyz}, {plotxz, plot}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Is it possible now on your chart to combine the projections of the curve with the corresponding projection of the implicit region? I mean just something like that (for example - sphere) https://ibb.co/vJqgbDv

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
ℛ = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}];

ClearAll[g, f, functions]

g[t_] := {Sin[t], Cos[1 - 3 t], Sin[2 t - 1]};

f[t_] := ConditionalExpression[g[t], g[t] ∈ ℛ];

plotrange = 1;
padding = .1;

functions[t_] := Prepend[f[t]] @ 
  MapThread[ReplacePart[f[t], # -> #2 (plotrange + padding)] &,
   {Thread[{1, {1, 2, 3}}], {-1, 1, -1}}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ functions[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> padding, 
 Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Row[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@functions[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> padding, 
    Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Small, 
    ViewPoint -> #] & /@ {{-∞, 0, 0}, {0, ∞, 0}, {0, 0, -∞}}, 
 Spacer[30]]
```

[image]

***Update:***

```
show = Show[ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@functions[t], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> padding, 
  Boxed -> {Back, Bottom, Left}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{-(plotrange + padding), Cos[t], Sin[t]}, 
    {Cos[t], (plotrange + padding), Sin[t]},
    {Cos[t], Sin[t], -(plotrange + padding)}}, {t, 0, 2 π}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin], PlotPoints -> 90], 
 RegionPlot3D[ℛ, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.3, Orange], PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

To add the intersection of the lines in the main plot with the surface of the ball:

```
lineswithendpoints = ParametricPlot3D[functions[t][[1]], {t, 0, 10}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
    PlotRange -> plotrange, PlotRangePadding -> padding] /. 
  Line[x_] :> {Line[x], Purple, Sphere[x[[{1, -1}]], .03]};

Show[show, lineswithendpoints]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would also like to add something, namely1: in one picture, combine the projection of the implicit region with the projection of the curve and mark the intersection points. 2. combine a three-dimensional curve and an implicit region with adjustable transparency on one plot.

Comment: For the 3D case, I did it like this: `Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{g[t]}, {t, 0, 10}],
   RegionPlot3D[\[ScriptCapitalR], PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.25],
    PlotPoints -> 50]}, ImageSize -> Small]`

Comment: @dtn, please see the update.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thank you very much for your help!